# PHP Warning: socket_recv() infinite waiting

Tags: php, windows, websocket, wampserver

I wrote below code to connect java web socket server. The client can connect succesfully to server.(I hope so).My problem is when I remove the line of socket_recv, it does not wait and throw any error. But php is waiting infinite on this line/block.

> PHP Version is 5.5.12

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$service_port = 2002;

$address = 'x.x.x.x';

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$input = "(({\"u\":\"994774100040\",\"ut\":0,\"lon\":28.838424,\"lox\":28.941421,\"lax\":41.074951,\"lan\":40.965122,\"rg\":0.0,\"pr\":0.0,\"di\":0.0,\"e\":false,\"p\":0,\"r\":0,\"l\":1,\"cr\":0,\"ac\":2,\"st\":0,\"t\":10,\"a\":5,\"ls\":1}))";
$out = '';

socket_write($socket, $input, strlen($input));
echo "OK.\n";

$buf = '';

//infinite waiting on below line
if (false !== ($bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 1024,0))) {
    echo "Read $bytes bytes from socket_recv(). Closing socket...";
} else {
    echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " .
    socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}
socket_close($socket);

echo $buf . "\n";
echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding below code for handshaking.:

```
$key = com_create_guid();
$header = "GET  HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header.= "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$header.= "Host: x.x.x.x:2002\r\n";
$header.= "Origin: http://localhost:81\r\n";
$header.= "Sec-WebSocket-Key: " . $key . "\r\n";
$header.= "\r\n";
socket_write($socket, $header, strlen($header));
```

Web socket server waits a header from client for handshaking.